# Java XML: how to escape '&', but skip '&amp;'

Tags: java, xml

I need to escape '&', but skip `&amp;`

I use next function

```
public static String translateAll(String input, String[] patterns, String[] replacements) {
    String result = input;

    for (int i = 0; i < patterns.length; i++) {
        result = result.replaceAll(patterns[i], replacements[i]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

...

```
private static final String[] decoded = { "&", "<", ">", "\"", "\'" };
private static final String[] encoded = { "&amp;", "&lt;", "&gt;", "&quot;", "&apos;" };

public static String escape(String input) {
    return translateAll(input, decoded, encoded);
}
```

...

```
String escapedBodyValue = XMLUtils.escape(originBodyValue);
```

It replaces all & with `&amp;`
but it also replaces all `&amp;` with `&amp;amp;`

So, how to skip already escaped characters?

Comment: Why is some of your data escaped already, but not all of it?

Comment: @immibis that's hard question, we have a server side system. But clients can send XML data in any form.

Comment: are you using an XML parser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input is messed up. I would consider *unescaping* everything into "normal form" with `&`, `<`, `>` unescaped, then escape the result. Using [`StringEscapeUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXml%28java.lang.String%29) (from Apache Commons lang) it looks like this:

```
String test = "aaa &amp; bbb & ccc &lt; ddd & eee.";
test = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(test));
```

Result:

```
aaa &amp; bbb &amp; ccc &lt; ddd &amp; eee.
```

---

If you really want to go ahead with your current solution, I'd recommend using something like:

```
test = test.replaceAll("&(?!.{2,4};)", "&amp;");
```

Break-down of the regex:

- `&`                 -- An `&` character
- `(?! ___ )` -- Not followed by `___`
- `.{2,4}`       -- Any 2, 3 or 4 characters
- `;`                 -- followed by a `;`

Comment: WOW, this really looks great, I will try it right away. Thanks man!

Comment: What do you recommend as the fastest solution:  StringEscapeUtils or proper 'replaceAll' ?

Comment: I'd go with the solution that is easiest to get right and to maintain (StringEscapeUtils). If your application has performance problems you profile it to find the bottlenecks. If this part of the code happens to be critical you can start doing some micro benchmarking / try different implementation such as the replaceAll variant.

Answer (score 7):

Don't do this. You just break things more than they are already... In 1 hour, you will realize that your approach also replaces `&quot;` by `&amp;quot;`, and you will need to do another hack...

Your escaping apparently *was* already busted before. Don't use string replacement to unbreak it, but try to **parse the data** back to what it is *supposed* to mean, **then use a proper encoder** that produces a correctly-escaped version.

In short: **never use `println` to produce XML**. Use an XML generator that does the escaping right.

See also this *famous* StackOverflow question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1060350

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a kludge but I would simply do what you're currently doing then just replace all `&amp;amp;` with `&amp;` (and others such as `&amp;lt;` back into `&lt;`), as many times as it takes until no more changes are possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this pattern will get you every "&" not followed by amp haha

```
&(?!(amp))
```

Comment: I think the inner parentheses are unnecessary.

Comment: oh yeah , just tried it and you are correct haha.. i was treating it as a java statement lol (negating the whole word) haha

Answer (score 0):

You can probably come up with a crazy regexp that will replace the single special characters, but not the character references. Note that you can also have entity references, and `&xxxx;` sequences (following what @Edward M.B. suggested it can be as simple as `&(?!([0-0a-zA-Z]+;))`).

If it doesn't work, you can write your own function that would read ahead, buffering, after finding a '&', and accumulate alpha-numeric characters until either ';' is met (at which point you dump the buffer), or a non-alphanumeric character is met, at which point you dump '&' and buffer except the first character.

However, what your question shows, is that you are mixing character data that shouldn't be mixed. The right approach is to never have strings that are half-encoded, and make sure you are either dealing with fully encoded, or fully raw data.

Answer (score 0):

Just used this, not really too efficient but it's a way

```
String test = "testin & with testing &amp;" 
test = test.replace("&", "&amp;");
test = test.replace("&amp;amp;", "&amp;");
```